# UITextview typingAttributes not working

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have UITextView and I want to set it's line height to 50.0f so I'm using typingAttributes, but nothing works, my code goes like this in ViewDidAppear Method

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight        = 50.0f;
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple       = 50.0f;
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight        = 50.0f;

NSDictionary *textViewAttributeDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
textView.typingAttributes  = textViewAttributeDic;
```

text doesn't effected by setting typingAttributes,and I tried to changed the color and font using typingAttributesbut nothing works

i've read all stack answers and documentation

what i'm doing wrong :(

*update:*
i even tried

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight        = 50.0f;
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple       = 50.0f;
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight        = 50.0f;

NSDictionary *textViewAttributeDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
textView.attributedText  = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"" attributes:textViewAttributeDic];
```

when I tried

```
textView.attributedText  = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"blahblah" attributes:textViewAttributeDic];
```

It worked, but i need empty textView with no spaces or 'blah' characters

Comment: After setting "blahblah" attributed string, try `textView.text = nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ios6 I solved it like this , in textView delegate I wrote:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

     // 1st save current selected range ... we gonna use this value in 5th step
     NSRange textViewCurrentRange =  textView.selectedRange;

     // 2nd disable scrolling in textview
     [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];

     // 3rd set the new enterd text as attributed string to textview
     [textView setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textView.text attributes:self.textAttributes]];

     // 4th enable scrolling
     [textView setScrollEnabled:YES];

     // 5th re set selected range so text inidicator will get back to it's place
     textView.selectedRange = textViewCurrentRange;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation clearly states that `typingAttributes` is for the editing mode of the text field.

> **typingAttributes**
>
> The attributes to apply to new text being entered by the user.
>
> ...
>   If the text field is not in editing mode, this property contains the value nil. Similarly, you cannot assign a value to this property unless the text field is currently in editing mode.

Instead, you should assign `attributedText` instead of the `text` property. The mechanism to specify the attributes is via `NSAttributedString` that you assign.

Comment: I cannot see how an empty text field can display the wrong attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You may configure paragraph style in IB using temporary text in text view and setting all required attributes. Then you clear your text view on launch `textView.text = nil`. Text attributes should remain the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically setting `attributedText` resets the `typingAttributes`. Set `typingAttributes` last.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one gotcha - as mentioned in other answers, the `UITextField` must be in editing mode for this to work. If you are running in the simulator, and the keyboard is hidden (cmd+k), the textfield is *not* in editing mode if you type using your computer's keyboard. Make sure the simulator's keyboard is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I took a hint from **@Mundi**'s answer.
In my case, I set `typingAttributes` when the viewController was created, and it did not work
I was entering code according to placeholder in `textViewShouldBeginEditing`, so I reset `typingAttributes` in that method, but it didn't work the same way.

When I saw **@Mundi**'s answer and resetting `typingAttributes` in `textViewDidBeginEditing`, it worked fine.

Comment: This reads an anecdote rather than an answer to *what i'm doing wrong?* Does it add anything to Mundi's 2013 answer?