# My UITextView text jumps to right after editing (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, uitextview

I wanted to create a couple of UITextViews that are editable. Everything works, but after editing (and clicking on the 'Done' button), the text moves just a little bit to the right. Very annoying! Is there a way to force the text in a UITextView to stay on the left side (left aligned)?

Thanks a lot!

Dide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Text Alignment.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/textAlignment)  From the documentation:

```
var textAlignment: NSTextAlignment
```

You may have to hard-set the [UITextView typing attributes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817651/uitextview-typingattributes-not-working)
Then again, if your problem is not that it stops being text-aligned to the left but rather that the whole thing becomes slightly indented, your issue may be with [Text Container Inset.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/textContainerInset)  You can read more about the inset [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-pad-a-uitextview-by-setting-its-text-container-inset).

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8);
```

Comment: Thanks Max! It was indeed a problem with the UIEdgeInsets.